# [cakePHP]$result does not show the result

Tags: php, cakephp

everybody. 
I need your help. I'd like to show $result on http://local/data , but it does not show the result of $result....

**index.ctp**

```
<h1>Index for Data testing</h1>
<p><?php $result ?></p>
<p>
    <?php 
    echo $this->Form->create(false,array('type'=>'post','action'=>'.'));
    echo $this->Form->label('text1',"message");
    echo $this->Form->text('text1');
    echo $this->Form->checkbox('check1');
    echo $this->Form->label('check1',"checkbox1");
    echo $this->Form->radio('radio1', array('male' => '男性','female' => '女性' ));
    echo $this->Form->select('select1', array("Mac" => 'マック', "Windows" => 'ウィンドウズ', "Linux" => 'リナックス'));
    echo $this->Form->end("Send");
    ?>
</p>
```

**DataController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('Sanitize','Utility');

class DataController extends AppController{


    public function index(){
        $this->modelClass = null;
        if($this->request->data){
            $result = "[result]";
            $result .="<br>text1:".Sanitize::stripAll($this->request->data['text1']);
            $result .="<br>check1:".$this->request->data['check1'];
            $result .="<br>radio1:".$this->request->data['radio1'];
            $result .="<br>select1:".$this->request->data['select1'];

        }else{
            $result = "no data.";
        }
        $this->set("result",$result);
    }

}
```

Could you kindly point what is wrong on my code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue

I forgot to input "echo".

index.ctp should be

```
<h1>Index for Data testing</h1>
<p><?php echo $result ?></p>
```

I am so stupid lol.